# htaccess removing .php ext causes infinite loop on admin login EE 2.10.1

Tags: ee2, htaccess, admin

when I use this htaccess its normal working good but it doesnt redirect .php urls

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
# RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

but when I change it to:

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

all .php extensions are redirects but admin login gets infinite loop redirect. it's a siteground hosting

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first block wouldn't mess with anything since it's all commented out. 
try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```